# How to update pandas dataframe values from a for loop based on row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I have a dataframe that looks something like this called `df` (as a minimum reproducible example):

```
     Brand     Price
0    Honda     22000
1    Toyota    25000
2    Ford      27000
3    Audi      35000
```

Essentially, I just want to duplicate the "Price" values and add that in another column, so that I'll have an output that'll look something like this:

```
     Brand     Price    Price_Copy
0    Honda     22000    22000
1    Toyota    25000    25000
2    Ford      27000    27000
3    Audi      35000    35000
```

My code and what I've tried:

```
for i in range(0, len(df)):
   df["Price_Copy"] = np.nan
   if "Price" in df.columns and not np.isnan(df.get("Price")[i]):
       df.at[i, "Price_Copy"] = int(df.get("Price")[i]) if isinstance(df.get("Price")[i], np.integer) 
       else np.nan
```

My resulting dataframe only updates the last value and looks something like this and doesn't keep the Price as an Integer (but that's another problem):

```
     Brand     Price    Price_Copy
0    Honda     22000    NaN
1    Toyota    25000    NaN
2    Ford      27000    NaN
3    Audi      35000    35000.0
```

I'm wondering how I'd be able to update all the values in the Price_Copy column to be a duplicate of the values in Price this way. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `df['Price_Copy'] = df.Price`

Comment: I used a simpler example here but I can't do that because I'm doing some error checking per row (e.g.```np.isnan(df.get("Price")[i])```)

Knew someone was gonna comment that and close this lmao

Comment: Sorry, not understand. I question is write need duplicate column, do you need something else? Can you change data sample with expected output?

Comment: Not a 100% duplicate column because I'm working with a much more complex dataset than what I've given in my example which requires me to check variable type in every row which is why I'm using a ```for``` loop for iteration. In theory, I only want certain variable types to be duplicated which is why I have the ```if``` conditions.

Comment: Ya, problem is if reopen, you got exatly this answer `df['Price_Copy'] = df.Price` or `df = df.assign(Price_Copy = df.Price)`, so ask why it not working.

Comment: So it is reason for ask change data with expected output, so not possible use simple `df['Price_Copy'] = df.Price`

Comment: Yeah I didn't use the best sample dataset for this, man stackoverflow is actually ruthless

Comment: ya, so please change it.

Comment: I wanted duplicate values but I mentioned that I wanted the values to be "duplicated this way", implying I wanted my logic to be fixed. Guess I wasn't clear enough haha

Comment: Ok, so need create new column only if this column exist and if exist there is at least one NaN? Or create new column if exist column `Price` ?

Comment: Create new column regardless,
Copy values only if ```Price``` exists for row and ```Price``` value for row is not NaN

Comment: OK, so if Price value is `nan` then what should be filled in new column? NaN? 1? -1?

Comment: If price value is nan, fill with 0

Comment: OK, so need `df['Price_Copy'] = np.where(df.Price.isna(), 0, df.Price)` ? Or `df['Price_Copy'] = df.Price.fillna(0)` ?